# humanize input javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, humanize

I want to title case form inputs using the humanize library and Jquery. So far I have this:

```
$("#FirstName,#LastName").blur(function () {
    Humanize.titleCase( $(this) )
});
```

but it gives me an error:

```
humanize.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: n.split is not a function
    at o (humanize.min.js:2)
    at Object.titleCase (humanize.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:3:14)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.r.handle (jquery-2.2.4.min.js:3)
```

Comment: `.titleCase` takes a *string* not an HTMLElement, nor a jQuery wrapped one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Humanize.titleCase( $(this) )
```

should be

```
Humanize.titleCase( $(this).val() );
```

**Update after @vlaz comment**

the full code will be something like

```
$("#FirstName,#LastName").blur(function () {
    $(this).val( Humanize.titleCase( $(this).val() ) );
});
```

Comment: Unless these are, say, `span`s or `div`s, in which chase it'd be `.text()`. And even then, the result would need to be written back to where it came from, else the callback effectively does nothing.

Comment: Yes, but normally `span` and `div`s will not have `blur` event unless they have tabindex 0